# Golang map key points to address value

Tags: go

How can I define a map, where the key points to an address of a struct?

i.e.

```
type A struct {
   id int
}

sessions = make(map[int]&A)
first := &A{6}
sessions[0] = first
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all in your code is fine, you only use a wrong declaration of pointer:

```
sessions := make(map[int]*A)
first := A{6}
sessions[0] = &first
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6d-Xgw1NOrF

Answer (score 2):

struct pointers can be achived by with a `*` before type as said [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types):

> PointerType = "*" BaseType .

so:

`sessions = make(map[int]*A)` is the answer